# How can i know my remaining Soundcloud API Limit?

Tags: php, soundcloud

I am working with Sound-Cloud API in my application for these i create some APIs. It was working fine yesterday but now its showing

> **error: string(47) "The requested URL responded with HTTP code 429.**

I checked Sound-Cloud documentation and find HTTP Code 429 related to [Too many request](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#errors).

Here my concern is How i can know count of my all requests and remaning request.

Comment: I have the same issue. Not using soundcloud playback requests, and getting error 429 way too often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Effective July 1, all requests that result in access to a playable stream are subject to a limit of 15,000 requests per any 24-hour time window. [Ref](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/rate-limits)

**NOTE**

There is no way to count, how many requests are remaining or used.

### Solution

1. You have to check, how many API request you have at one page? Reduce them as much as you can.
2. You can create multiple API KEYS and use them randomly.
3. You can make cache of your queries.